# Letting someone know I don't speak Spanish well

Tags: traducción

I will be traveling to Mexico next month, and I want to be able to tell people that I do not speak Spanish very well. I do speak some spanish, but only what I've been able to teach myself in the last year or so.

Would saying `no hablo español muy bien`, convey that I only speak a little Spanish? Or would there be a phrase that better illustrates that my Spanish is bad, without making them think that they cannot talk to me in Spanish at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying

> No hablo español muy bien

conveys perfectly the message. You could also use

> Mi español es todavía un poco limitado

to express that you still haven't mastered all the complexity of verb tenses in Spanish, are still building your vocabulary and maybe, since you are self-taught, your conversation skills.

Answer (score 3):

I always say 'Hablo muy poquito Espanol" to let people know I speak very little Spanish and they seem to understand perfectly. If you can speak a fair amount you can change 'poquito' to 'poco'. Good luck!